# Is there any app like Skyscanner but for hostels?

Tags: web-apps

Skyscanner scrapes data and is able to find the cheapest possible flight option, even if it requires odd connections.

Hostel prices also fluctuate. Is there any service which helps you book the cheapest overall stay in a city for a period of time, even if it requires an inconvenient amount of moving around?

Comment: There are dozens of these competing in the hotel booking market.  Have you checked if any of them also do hostels?

Comment: I have had a good experience with [booking.com](http://booking.com) for hotels and if you want it even cheaper with [www.airbnb.de](http://www.airbnb.de).